# Why can't I open FaceTime on my 4g iPod?

Tags: ipod-touch, facetime

I don't know how to get my FaceTime to work. It says "turn on FaceTime" when I open the app, then I click on it and it says "FaceTime Activation: An error occurred during activation. Try again." How do I get it to work?

Comment: Certain countries do not allow facetime, where are you?

Answer (score 1):

Try rebooting your iPod Touch by holding down the power and home buttons until you see the Apple logo. (Keep holding them through the part where it says "slide to power off".)

Answer (score 1):

Check the date/time in Settings on your iPod.

Answer (score 0):

I think is your DNS problem.

You may solve like this.

http://www.justin.my/2012/01/facetime-activation-an-error-occurred-during-activation-try-again-while-using-wifi/

Comment: Could you add more detail into the answer? Links go dead and this information may not be accessable in the future.